# React native open firefox browser in anonymous mode

Tags: javascript, react-native, firefox, browser, mozilla

Is there a way to open the firefox browser anonymously?

I  know that using Linking it is possible to open a url on the browser defined as the favorite, but I can't understand if there is a way to open it anonymously.

Comment: what do you mean by `anonymously`? does it mean `incognito mode` or `private window`?

Comment: I mean incognito mode.